# Objective-C Blocks in C

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

While reading through the blocks conceptual overview in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxOverview.html), I saw the following statement:

> Although blocks are available to pure C and C++, a block is also
>   always an Objective-C object.

How is this possible? I mean an Objective-C object available in pure C. I'm getting confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How is this possible? I mean an Objective-C object available in pure C.

Matt Gallagher wrote [an article that nicely explains how blocks work](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html). In a nutshell, blocks are defined as structs that meet the requirements to be a valid Objective-C object (for example, the struct starts with an `isa` pointer). None of this causes a problem for C, and the compiler knows what the definition of a block is, so even when compiling plain old C it can still do the right thing to make blocks work.

The added Objective-C aspect of blocks doesn't affect how blocks are used in C, but still provides the ability to treat blocks as objects so that they can be added to collections and otherwise managed like any other object.

This isn't really so strange. If you think about it, *all* Objective-C objects are "available" in C at some level -- the [entire Objective-C runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) consists of C functions that manipulate structures that represent Objective-C objects and classes. And even disregarding that, blocks aren't the first example of a data type that's usable in both C and Objective-C -- we've had [toll free bridging](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/bridge.html) between Foundation and Core Foundation for many years. The implementation of blocks may be somewhat different, but it's not a new thing to have objects that work in both worlds.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. One thing, the compiler would still need to recognize the block syntax (For e.g. the ^ symbol) right? i.e. Like chuck said the compiler would still need to be incorporated with support for blocks?

Comment: Yes, you still need a blocks-capable compiler and a blocks-capable runtime library. On OS X and iOS that's clang and libclosure.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C can be freely mixed with C. As long as your class has a C API (which blocks do, with Block_copy, Block_release, etc.), the C code doesn't care if it's implemented in Objective-C or C.

Comment: So Objective-C is different from C in only the language semantics?

Comment: @Rakesh: Well, it also has different semantics. But the big point is that C is a subset of of Objective-C.

Comment: I understand that, and that is what makes this confusing for me. Since C is a subset of Objective-C, how is it that an Objective-C object can be used in a pure C code. Or is it possible for a C(only) compiler to compile code which has blocks in it?

Comment: @Rakesh: Well, the compiler has to support blocks. They aren't actually a part of standard C; they're an extension that Apple added in Clang. But they can be used in a C file because Objective-C is binary compatible with C.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks. The binary compatible part made it sufficiently clear.

Comment: @Chuck could you please explain what does being binary compatible mean?

Comment: @ajay: It means that the code produced by the Objective-C compiler is such that it can be linked into a C program with its public data visible and its public functions callable. Basically, they both compile to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

From the same document,

```
float (^oneFrom)(float);

oneFrom = ^(float aFloat) {
    float result = aFloat - 1.0;
    return result;
};
```

oneFrom a variable referencing the block (object) `{ float result = aFloat - 1.0; return result; }`

Blocks are available to pure C and C++, ie. the block can consist of pure C or C++ code.