# Create an Objective-C Block in plain C++

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I want to create a `CGDisplayStream` with the `CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue` c function, which expects an `CGDisplayStreamFrameAvailableHandler` as parameter.
`CGDisplayStreamFrameAvailableHandler` is an objective-c block.
I tried to use a c++ lambda but this doesnt work:

`No viable conversion from '(lambda at ###RECTRACTED###)' to 'CGDisplayStreamFrameAvailableHandler' (aka 'void (^)(CGDisplayStreamFrameStatus, uint64_t, IOSurfaceRef _Nullable, CGDisplayStreamUpdateRef _Nullable)')`

I found: [Objective-C Blocks in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539333/objective-c-blocks-in-c)
but this doesnt really help, since they didnt explain what is needed to create an objective-c block in plain c or c++.

How can i create a valid object which i can pass to CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue?

Comment: Have you tried just creating a block? As the docs say, Apple's compilers have support for blocks in both C and C++. (The question you linked wonders how the implementation is possible, not how to use them.)

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks, this works. Its a little bit frustrating to use the apple specific compilers :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

`CGDisplayStreamFrameAvailableHandler handler = ^void(CGDisplayStreamFrameStatus status, uint64_t timestamp, IOSurfaceRef frameSurface, CGDisplayStreamUpdateRef updateRef) {
        std::cout << "Update" << std::endl;
};`

Thanks to @molbdnilo for the help.